# Which stand or adapter for Colorspike light fixture?

Tags: light, lightstands

I have these [ColorSpike](https://colorspike.com) lights that I want to put on a stand. They come with a stand adapter that ends with a 5/8" male stud. So now I am confused: apparently, usually these studs appear on the stands, not the lights.

So which kind of light stand or adapter should I buy? I tried to look at all the light stand accessories at B&H, but I could not find a solution and I am really confused

In the photo, I hold the ColorSpike fixture in front of a screen that shows the top of a typical stand that I found online.

[image: CorlorSpike mounting fixture]

Thanks Mike Sowsun for your detailed answer. I am now the proud owner of the second Light Stand Bracket that you showed. I can fix the ColorSpike fixture on it, but at the other end there is a fixed protruding screw, which doesn't seem easy to fit on a standard tripod. See these two new photos:

[image: disassembled light mounting bracket]

[image: CorlorSpike picture on bracket]

Comment: Colorspike sell their own bracket. I can't find on their site where to buy it & their picture is a bit small - better pic at the bottom of https://www.newsshooter.com/2018/11/08/colorspike-rgb-light-by-bitbanger/ no idea what you'd call it so can't provide an actual answer.

Comment: Yes but there is no way to order it, and they don't reply to queries :-(

Comment: Most light stand swivel brackets have 5/8” stud receptacles at each end. I have never seen one before with a fixed threaded 1/4” thread at one end. There is a huge selection of adapters available online. You should be able to find something that will connect the fixed end of that bracket to your light stand, but I would buy another bracket that has proper 5/8” stud receptacles in both ends.

Answer (score 1):

You need an adjustable [Light Stand Bracket](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/98613-REG/Cool_Lux_MD5300_MD_5300_Adjustable_Light_and.html) which has receptacles for 5/8” studs on both ends. They are designed to allow you to position the light at any angle and most of them allow the use of an umbrella for reflecting the light on your subject.

[image]

Near the bottom of the ColorSpike webpage is a photo that shows an optional "swivel Mounting Kit".

[image]

These last 2 photos are from the “ColorSpike” webpage and show examples of how the lights can be mounted to a light stand with a standard bracket.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Colorspike actually sell their own bracket - stud holes both ends. Neither of the first two  pictures you posted would work. The second two could be anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to buy ColorSpike's own mounting kit. I sent them queries, but they never replied. I now have the second bracket you show. I can remove the stud on one end, but the other end has a removable hot shoe connector under which there is a fixed screw. So I am no closer to a solution :-(

Comment: I edited my questions with two photos to show the problem